# get the link of the uploaded file using blobstore handlers

Tags: python, file, google-app-engine, blobstore

i can upload a file using uploadhandler in python.while i am trying to get the url of the file i am getting error as "Assertionerror images the service doesn't hve CreateRbc method()
please help me

```
class ServeHandler(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreDownloadHandler):
  def get(self, blob_info):
    blob_info = images.get_serving_url(blob_info)
    self.get_serving_url(blob_info)
```

Answer (score 3):

From what I understood you are a bit confused on what is what.

The [`get_serving_url()`](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/images/functions#Image_get_serving_url) takes as a parameter a `blob_key` and not a `blob_info` and returns a String, which is a URL for a particular image with some extra goodies that you can add in the end of that URL (=s512-c or =s256).

The `ServeHandler` that you have in your snippet is an attempt to create a general serving handler for any Blob I would guess, but still is totally broken from many points. I would strongly suggest you to go through the [overview](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/overview), where you can see a fully working example on how to upload and serve files using Google App Engine, to begin with.